# Highmaps won't display my GeoJSON lake layer

Tags: highcharts, geojson

I don't succeed in adding a final layer to my Highmaps. I have already the ground map and some additional layers. But the lake layer does not succeed to be displayed. Why is that? It does load into QGIS correctly.

Truth is, by the way, that I haven't understood the difference between calling a GeoJSON file like this (which works for my additional layers):

```
type: 'mapline',
data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['lakes'], 'mapline'),
```

or like this (which works for the ground layer):

```
mapData: Highcharts.maps['lakes'],
data : data,
```

But not sure if this is relevant here. It doesn't work the one or the other way. [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/zyp26e04/6/).

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by one of the geometry which has null value:

```
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": null,
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID": 13,
      "NAME": "Lake St. Martin",
      "Shape_Leng": 1.1857234063,
      "Shape_Area": 0.0450760801303
    }
  }
```

After removing the incorrect item everything works as it should. As to your second question: please also check `chart.map` property: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/chart.map and a precise description here: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=39602

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ga396zwo/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.geojson

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mapline.mapData

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mapline.data

Comment: Grrr... How do you detect these kind of problems?! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi @luftikus143, I use only browser console and DevTools.